# Wrap a material component (mat-select) inside a component of mine

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-template-form

I'm trying to use [mat-select](https://v11.material.angular.io/components/select/overview) of Angular Material 11.2.12.

Since I need to make **mat-select** do some stuff (filter, select/deselect all) besides its default behavior, I need to put it inside a component of mine.

Something like this:

```
<my-component>    
    <mat-select #select [formControlName]="selectControl" multiple>  
     <my-stuff>bla bla bla</my-stuff>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredItems" [value]="item.value">{{ item.text }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>    
</my-component>
```

What should I do inside `<my-component>` to be able to use `<my-component>` inside a form, as I'm now able to use `<mat-select>` inside a form.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor . You can refer example such as https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a FormControl to a child component - No value accessor for form control with unspecified name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099559/passing-a-formcontrol-to-a-child-component-no-value-accessor-for-form-control)

Comment: Thanks everybody, I'll take a look :)

Comment: Thanks guys, those answers solve my problem