Error integrating Angular Material's chip component into my form
I want to include the chip component in my form component.
For this I use the chip from Angular Material.
https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples#chips-form-control
The error appears:
Type 'AbstractControl<any, any> | null' is not assignable to type 'FormControl'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'FormControl'.
I don't know what I have to do differently. I did it according to the instructions.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54136348/19648465
Can someone please help me?
Here is the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6lpefu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.html

 <app-chip [control]="$any(form).get('subTasks')"></app-chip>. can you try this..?

You need to type cast it, by default all form controls and groups are Abstract Controls.
Add a function in form.component as below
  public get formControl () {
    return this.form.get("subTasks") as FormControl;
  }

And change you html as below
...
  <app-chip [control]="formControl"></app-chip>
...

This should compile the code for you. And check what angular version are you using and choose that version in the version dropdown as below and use according to the instructions.


How do I get the subtasks Array in the HTML Template? When using formControl.value I get the error. Type any must have a Symbol.iterator method that returns an iterator.
